# Use char* or void* or something else for byte fields in C++?

Tags: c++

I have some byte fields which contain a field of different numerical types. Pointers to these fields are then passed around and stored as members in other classes.

Should I use `char*` or `void*` for the pointer type?

Currently, I see just one advantage for `char*`: You can not dereference `void*`. This is not an issue when reading a value out of the field, since I have to cast into the respective pointer type anyways. In case I want to do a plain copy of a field byte-by-byte, I would first need to cast the `void*` into a `char*`, so it would be easyier to directly store it as `char*`.

**Or are there any reasons against using `char*`?**

Generally, I would prefer to stay as low-level as possible, since I have to pass the fields to other low-level interfaces.

Comment: How do you encode what's behind the pointer, like answering which one of different numerical types are this pointer pointing to ?

Comment: It should mainly depend on your concern, if you like to treat the memory as an opaque, `void *` will prevent you from accident dereference, if you like to to code/decode the memory, a semantic data type, like `char*`, `unsigned int *`, etc. is preferred.

Comment: @Jojje: There are different ways how this happens. For example, the field is sent to a function which always expects doubles in it. But generally this question should not play a role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using char* for memory blobs is "easy to use" (e.b. byte by byte operations) however it is very bad for reading and understanding the code (you still see it in various API's however).

If your data is just a blob of memory then better use void*.

Only if your data is an array of a specific type (char, int, uint8_t, some struct, ...), then use a pointer of that type.

If you need to treat a struct as "byte data" (for example to calculate a hash) you can internally treat it as "char*" (or uint8_t* or uint_32_t* or whatever you need there). However the public API should still be void* if you don't require a specific memory layout.

The point is: if you have an API using void* you can supply any type of pointer to it (which is the point of a hash function). However you always need a reinterpret_cast if you use char*.

Answer (score 2):

Using `char` can raise some problems - it all depends on how do you want to treat values stored behind such pointers.

The problem is, that `byte` is usually interpreted as unsigned value. For example: UTF-8 encoding. It produces sequence of bytes, [that can have different values, depending on encoded code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). If we used signed type, we would have to cast value to an unsigned one to able to properly check their values (code points greater than `U+007F` are always translated to sequence of bytes, in which all of them have sign bit set to 1).

But whether `char` is signed or not is implementation-dependent. In fact, C++ standard defines three distinct types:

- char
- signed char
- unsigned char

If you include `#include <limits.h>`, you can look at `CHAR_MIN`:

- if defined to 0, `char` is **unsigned**
- if defined to some negative value (usually -128), char is **signed**

So, what it all means?

You should store bytes in a way, that will allow you to read/write their values without additional checks. You probably want your bytes to be an unsigned values, so define new type (as [many](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) [high-level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx) [languages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2ayt412.aspx) do):

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;
```

And then, define your pointers as:

```
Byte* data_pointer;
```

Then, if your functions expect 'void*' or 'Byte*', nothing needs to be done. However, if they expect pointers to a particular numeric type (`int`, `float`, etc.), you will need to `reinterpret_cast` them.

Comment: I will always cast the values in the byte field to a clearly defined datatype before I use them. W plan to use char* or void* only when passing the byte field around in the program. So does this answer actually correspond to the question?

Comment: Yes. You will need to cast these pointers anyway, but defining them as pointers to `Byte`, allows you to easily and portable use them, if you decide at some point, that certain function should use such pointers as byte sequence to perform byte-by-byte operations. That is exactly the same reason you mentioned in your question, but using portable type, that behaves identically on all platforms is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and low on resources is a simple union of typed pointers, as I understand the actual type is by context which makes this a good fit.

To be on the other end with runtime dynamic there is
[Boost::Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html)